# ruby script executed from php not working, but ruby script works fine alone

Tags: php, ruby

so i have ruby script that simply writes to a test.txt file with "hello"

i have a php script that executes this ruby script, when a user clicks a link.

i find that test.txt is empty.

however when i run by itself

$> ruby sayhi.rb

test.txt is filled with "hello"

Comment: Include the PHP code that 1. Generates the ruby command to call 2. Actually executes the ruby command.  If the code is too long to post, you didn't spend enough time trying to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite probably that your webserver does not have permissions to write to that file. Trying using `chmod -R 777` on the folder containing the text file.